# For Loop with input confirmation after n iterations with pymssql

Tags: python, pymssql

I am updating a database table with a dictionary with this code:

```
cursor = conn.cursor()
for key in dRt:                          
    x = dRt[key]                          
    sql = 'UPDATE table SET R = %s WHERE %s = ID'
    cursor.execute(sql, (x, key))
conn.commit()
conn.close()
```

My dictionary got several thousand entries. Is it possible to add a part to the code which asks, after writing 1000 rows into the database, if it should continue?

I tried something like this:

```
cursor = conn.cursor()
counter = 0
for key in dRt:                         
    x = dRt[key]                         
    sql = 'UPDATE table SET R = %s WHERE %s = ID'
    if counter == 1000:
        break
    eingabe = input("Beenden? Enter drücken!\n")
    cursor.execute(sql, (x, key))
conn.commit()
conn.close()
```

But this does not work correctly.

Comment: You're not incrementing your `counter`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Conditionally initialising an input based on counter should work. After initialising an input you should also reset the counter to 0.

```
cursor = conn.cursor()
counter = 0
for key in dRt:
    counter += 1                         
    x = dRt[key]                         
    sql = 'UPDATE table SET R = %s WHERE %s = ID'
    if counter == 1000:
        input("Beenden? Enter drücken!\n")
        counter = 0
cursor.execute(sql, (x, key))
conn.commit()
conn.close()
```

Comment: This does one update because `execute` is not in the loop and and the results of the call to `input` are never tested and so it serves no purpose.

Answer (score 0):

It's okay to have an `input` statement in the loop, but execution will stop until something is entered. You must then check to see what was entered to determine whether you want to continue or not:

```
cursor = conn.cursor()
sql = 'UPDATE table SET R = %s WHERE %s = ID' # moved out of the loop
counter = 0
for key in dRt:
    counter += 1                         
    x = dRt[key]                                 
    cursor.execute(sql, (x, key))     # moved higher in the loop
    if counter == 1000:               # now we have done the next 1000 updates
        reply = input("Beenden? Enter drücken!\n")
        if reply == '':
            break # anything else entered than just enter, for example "geh", and we continue
        counter = 0
conn.commit()
conn.close()
```